# How do I input n repetitions of a digit in bash, interactively

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history, line-editor

I'd like to run the command

```
foo --bar=baz <16 zeroes>
```

How do I type the 16 zeroes efficiently*?  If I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> it will repeat the next thing 160 times, which is not what I want.  In emacs I can either use <kbd>Alt-[number]</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, but in bash <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> kills the currently-being-typed line and the next zero just adds a 0 to the line.

If I do

```
foo --bar=baz $(printf '0%.0s' {1..16})
```

Then `history` shows exactly the above, and not `foo --bar=baz 0000000000000000`; i.e. bash doesn't behave the way I want. (**Edit**: point being, I want to input some number of zeroes without using `$(...)` command substitution)

(*) I guess a technical definition of "efficiently" is "with O(log n) keystrokes", preferably a number of keystrokes equal to the number of digits in 16 (for all values of 16) plus perhaps a constant; the emacs example qualifies as efficient by this definition.

Comment: Sounds like you want bash to just somehow `know what you want to do`. In a complex nested command how would bash know which parts you wanted to see the result of the execution in the history as opposed to the command itself? What about variables? In short bash is always going to have the `code` in the history, not the result of executing the code.

Comment: @meuh, `Alt` by itself doesn't send any character, so pressing and releasing alt won't have any effect as far as `bash` is concerned.

Comment: @Unbeliever Do What I Mean and it'll be Okay

Comment: @Unbeliever: see my edit—the point of the paragraph having to do with `history` was that I would like to input digits without using command substitution.

Comment: Whenever you want things typed automatically for you, AutoKey is a great utility to use. With it, you can build phrase substitutions, or complete Python macros that will do almost anything you like when a trigger phrase is typed or a hotkey is pressed. I didn't include this as an answer because it requires a GUI desktop environment and the rest of the answers do not - and are thus more generally applicable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
echo Alt+1Alt+6Ctrl+V0
```

That's 6 key strokes (assuming a US/UK QWERTY keyboard at least) to insert those 16 zeros (you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> for both 1 and 6).

You could also use the standard `vi` mode (`set -o vi`) and type:

```
echo 0Escx16p
```

(also 6 key strokes).

The `emacs` mode equivalent and that could be used to repeat more than a single character (`echo 0Ctrl+WAlt+1Alt+6Ctrl+Y`) works in `zsh`, but not in `bash`.

All those will also work with `zsh` (and `tcsh` where that comes from). With `zsh`, you could also use padding variable expansion flags and expand them with <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
echo ${(l:16::0:)}Tab
```

(A lot more keystrokes obviously).

With `bash`, you can also have `bash` expand your `$(printf '0%.0s' {1..16})` with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+E</kbd>. Note though that it will expand everything (not globs though) on the line.

To play the game of the least number of key strokes, you could bind to some key a widget that expands `<some-number>X` to `X` repeated `<some-number>` times. And have `<some-number>` in base 36 to even further reduce it.

With `zsh` (bound to <kbd>F8</kbd>):

```
repeat-string() {
  REPLY=
  repeat $1 REPLY+=$2
}
expand-repeat() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o rematchpcre
  local match mbegin mend MATCH MBEGIN MEND REPLY
  if [[ $LBUFFER =~ '^(.*?)([[:alnum:]]+)(.)$' ]]; then
    repeat-string $((36#$match[2])) $match[3]
    LBUFFER=$match[1]$REPLY
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
zle -N expand-repeat
bindkey "$terminfo[kf8]" expand-repeat
```

Then, for 16 zeros, you type:

```
echo g0F8
```

(3 keystrokes) where `g` is `16` in base 36.

Now we can further reduce it to one key that inserts those 16 zeros, though that would be cheating. We could bind <kbd>F2</kbd> to two `0`s (or two `$STRING`, 0 by default), <kbd>F3</kbd> to 3 `0`s, <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> to 16 `0`s... up to 19... possibilities are endless when you can define arbitrary widgets.

Maybe I should mention that if you press and hold the <kbd>0</kbd> key, you can insert as many zeros as you want with just one keystroke :-)

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple variations for `vi` and others!

Answer (score 8):

Presuming your terminal emulator doesn't eat the keystroke (e.g., to switch tabs)—plain xterm works—you can press <kbd>Alt-1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. The control-V is needed in there to break up the number and the character to repeat (if you were repeating a letter, you wouldn't need it).

(This is a readline feature known as `digit-argument`, so you should be able to use `bind` to change the modifier keys involved)

Comment: Thank you, including the name of the feature is useful when people like me stumble on these questions. Related links for a bit more reading: [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562115/press-alt-numeric-in-bash-and-you-get-arg-numeric-what-is-that) and [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Arguments.html)

Answer (score 4):

In Emacs, I'd normally use <kbd>C-q</kbd> to separate prefix argument from digit input.

Bash uses <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> instead of <kbd>C-q</kbd>, to avoid problems with XON/XOFF flow control.

So you can use <kbd>Alt+1</kbd> <kbd>Alt+6</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

another option is to type four zeroes and then use the mouse to copy and paste it three more times.  double-click to select, middle-click x 3 to paste.

Comment: Or golf it / cheat some more by typing *one* zero, select & paste that to get 2; select & paste that to get 4; select & paste to 8, and again for 16. It's POWerful :)

Comment: yeah, but typing 4 zeroes and repeat-pasting them seems the optimal level of effort vs payoff to me.  all that extra copying and pasting seems like work.

Answer (score 3):

#### Playing with macros:

Bind the function key <kbd>F8</kbd> to multiply by two the last *word* (up the previous space) (F8 key code found by using `Ctrl-V F8`):

```
$ bind '"\e[19~": "\C-w\C-y\C-y"'
```

That could be made permanent by sending the same text to `~/.inputrc`

```
$ echo '"\e[19~": "\C-w\C-y\C-y"' >> ~/.inputrc
```

then type:

> echo 0<kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>

to get 2^4 times the zero. (still 5 keystrokes).

or type:

> echo book<kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>

to get 2^3 book words.

#### Still faster:

Multiply by 4:

```
$ bind '"\e[19~": "\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y"'
```

> echo 0<kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>

3 keypress.

Multiply by 8 (the same number as the function key)

```
$ bind '"\e[19~": "\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y"'
```

> echo 00<kbd>F8</kbd>

Still 3 keypresses.

#### Cheat?

Cheat by multipling by 16.

```
$ bind '"\e[19~": "\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y\C-w\C-y\C-y"'
```

> echo 0<kbd>F8</kbd>

Only 2 keypress. (and still an useful simple function)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (base 36? Hah!) :-P

## Plainly cheating:

```
$ bind '"\e[19~": "0000000000000000"'
```

> echo <kbd>F8</kbd>

Just 1 (yes: **one**) keystroke.

---

---

#### Changing the binding for <kbd>ctrl+U</kbd>:

Send this to `~/.inputrc`:

```
echo '"\C-u": universal-argument >> ~/.inputrc
```

Re-read the `~/.inputrc` file:

```
ctrl+Xctrl+R
```

do it as is usual in emacs (as you wanted):

> foo --bar=baz <kbd>ctrl+U</kbd> 16 <kbd>ctrl+U</kbd> 0

7 keys (after the "setting up").

#### Slightly shorter:

Use the default "multiply by 4" of "universal-argument" and end with

```
 ctrl+V 0
```

> foo --bar=baz <kbd>ctrl+U</kbd><kbd>ctrl+U</kbd><kbd>ctrl+V</kbd>0

Only 5 keys.

#### Using the <kbd>alt+n</kbd> access to (arg: n)

```
 foo --bar=baz Alt+16Ctrl+V0
```

That's 6 keys to get the 16 zeros.

#### Not changing any keyboard shortcut:

If in your bash you have `bash C-u kills the currently-being-typed line`.
That's because `"\C-u":` is bind to `unix-line-discard`.

But that might also help:
When, what is before the cursor is erased, it is also placed in the "kill-ring".

So `ctrl+u` erases and `ctrl+y` yanks back what was erased.
On a clean line: Type `00` erase it and yank it back twice to make it `0000`.
Repeat to get `00000000` (8 zeros), finally type the command and yank back twice.

The first set (7 keys keep <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed):

```
00 ctrl+Uctrl+Yctrl+Y ctrl+U
```

The second set (5 keys)

```
ctrl+Uctrl+Yctrl+Y ctrl+U
```

That will get eight zeros in the erase ring, then type what you want:

```
 foo --bar=baz ctrl-Y ctrl-Y
```

to get:

```
foo --bar=baz 0000000000000000
```

After you get the idea, you may as well, type what you need, go to the start of the line (<kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd>), do as above (up to eight zeros) go to the end (<kbd>ctrl-E</kbd>) and yank twice.

> foo --bar=baz <kbd>ctrl-A</kbd>00 <kbd>ctrl-U</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-U</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-U</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-E</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd><kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd>

That's 15 keys (beside the command itself).
Not short, I know, but that is working only with what was available.

This is a little shorter:

> 0000 <kbd>ctrl-U</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-Y</kbd> ctrl-A foo --bar=baz

That's 11 keys

Comment: See edit of my answer ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Using macros? Base 36? Only in zsh? C'mon ... see my edit :-P

Comment: Well yes, the base36 was a bit tongue in cheek. I like your `F<n>` duplicating the last word `<n>` times.

Comment: Note that not all terminal send the same sequence upon F8 (though most of those found on GNU/Linux systems do send `^[[19~`). See `"$(tput kf8)"` to get the information from the terminfo database (or the `$terminfo` hash in `zsh`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, that's correct. Or simply use `ctrl-v F8`

Answer (score 2):

As a variation of [cas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315456/80216#315464),
type

```
printf '0%.s' {1..16}Enter
```

and then use the mouse to copy and paste it (once). 
Arguably, this is O(log n), but since it is (len(str(n))+20),
you might consider it inefficient. 
But note:

- I was able to shave off one character —
  on my system, `%.s` seems to behave the same as `%.0s`.
- If you want to run multiple commands
  with `0000000000000000` as an argument, you need to do this only once.

[glenn jackman points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315456/80216#comment554823_315538) that
`printf "%0*d\n" number 0`
(where *number* is a positive integer)
will print a string of *number* zeros (and a newline),
as the asterisk in the format
tells `printf` to take the field width from the arguments. 
Specifically, `printf "%0*d" 16 0` will print 16 zeros. 
But this is a special case that handles *only* `0`. 
`printf "%0*d" 16 12345` will print `0000000000012345`,
and `printf "%0*d" 16 foo` will print `0000000000000000`
and an error message. 
By contrast, the other commands in this answer
will produce strings like `123451234512345…` or `foofoofoo…`
(and see below for `7%7%7%...`).

If you’re going to do this on a frequent basis,
you can streamline it by defining a shell function:

```
rep() { printf -- "$1%.0s" $(seq 1 "$2"); printf "\n"; }
```

Notes:

- Use `$(seq 1 "$2")` instead of `(1.."$2"}` because the latter won’t work
  — see [this](/q/88216/80216), [this](/q/55392/80216), [this](/q/7738/80216), and [this](/q/180770/80216). 
  Note that some of the answers to those questions suggest using `eval`,
  but this is generally not recommended.
- The format string (`$1%.0s`) must be in double quotes
  (rather than single quotes) because it contains a parameter (`$1`).
- The `--` is to protect against `$1` values beginning with **`-`**.
- You could get similar protection by using `"%.0s$1"` instead of `"$1%.0s"`.
- Either way, a `$1` value containing `%` will cause it to choke.
- If you need to be able to handle `$1` values containing `%`, do

  ```
  rep() { local i; for ((i=0; i<$2; i++)); do printf '%s' "$1"; done; printf "\n"; }
  ```

Also, once you have such a function defined, you can do things like

```
foo --bar=baz "$(rep 0 16)"
```

which is slightly less typing than `"$(printf '0%.0s' {1..16})"`.

Comment: Alternately `printf "%0*d" 16 0` will print 16 zeros. The asterisk in the format will take the field width from the arguments